# vuexjs getter with argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Is there a way to pass parameter into getter of `vuex` `store`? 
Something like:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  getters: {
    someMethod(arg){
       // return data from store with query on args
    }
  }
})
```

So that in component I could use

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{someMethod(this.id)}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { mapGetters } from "vuex"

    export default {
        props: ['id'],
        computed: mapGetters(['someMethod'])
        }
    }
</script>
```

but in vuex first argument is `state` and second is other `getters`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

One way to do this can be:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  getters: {
    someMethod(state){
      var self = this;
       return function (args) {
          // return data from store with query on args and self as this
       };       
    }
  }
})
```

However, getter does not take arguments and why is explained in this [thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/145):

> the naming convention is slightly confusing, getters indicates state can be retrieved in any form, but in fact they are reducers.
>
> Perhaps we should have reducers being pure methods. Which can be used for filtering, mapping ect.
>
> getters then can be given any context. Similar to computed, but you can now combine computed props to getters in vuex option. Which helps structure of components.

**Edit:**

A better way to achieve the same thing will be using ES6 arrow as detailed out in the answer of [nivram80](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288003/1610034), using [method style getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) where you can pass a parameter by returning a function form the getter:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  getters: {
    someMethod: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.things.find(thing => thing.id === id)
      }
    };       
  }
})
```

Comment: The main purpose of getters/computed variables is to cache results. Do you know if it applies (and how) in this special case? Ta.

Comment: @xpuu look at this question for a short analysis of the caching: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575886/vuex-mapping-getter-with-argument-cached

Answer (score 125):

An ES6 arrow function would work nicely here too.  For example, sake, let's say you're looking for a particular 'thing' in your store.

```
new Vuex.Store({
  getters: {
    someMethod: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.things.find(thing => thing.id === id)
    }
  },
})
```

Here is another example via the [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access)

Comment: Perfect. I'm using this technique for very similar purpose. Instead of this:
`let something = this.$store.state.things && this.$store.state.things.thing ? this.$store.state.things.thing : null`,
I can now do `let something = this.$store.getters.getThings('thing')`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as a) it answers the question, and b) it doesn't promote bad practices. Accepted answer is just bad, it should be removed.

Comment: When i'm doing this I get the error: do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers. I know it works I've done this before but now I'm stuck on it :/

Answer (score 24):

You can pass arguments to getters by returning a function. This is particularly useful when you want to query an array in the store:

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
```

Inside your vue component:

```
store.getters.getTodoById(2) // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

Note that getters accessed via methods will run each time you call them, and the result is not cached.

The above answer is fetched from official Vue docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access

Answer (score 5):

You can use the MapGetters helper like this, once define store getters:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  getters: {
    someMethod(state){
       return (value) => {
          return value;
       }
    }
  }
})
```

Then call getter from a component like this:

```
<script>
    import { mapGetters } from "vuex"

    export default {
     computed: {
     ...mapGetters(['someMethod'])
     },
     mounted() {
       console.log(this.someMethod('hello world')); // then logs "hello world"
     }       
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that this is what a vuex.getter is meant to do.

first, as you can see in all the above examples the getter can be mapped as a computed only

```
<script>
    import { mapGetters } from "vuex"

    export default {
     computed: {
     ...mapGetters(['someGetter'])
     },
     mounted() {
       console.log(this.someGetter); // a computed is not a method.
     }       
}
</script>
```

and if you need it to receive arguments, what you want is a method, not a computed.

I would recommend you to used an store.action instead:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    someMethod({ state }, arg){
       // do something with state.someValue and the arg
       return someTransformationOfYourState;
    }
  }
})
```

as actions and mutations can be mapped as methods.
and you can use it like this:

```
<script>
    import { mapActions } from "vuex"

    export default {
     computed: {
     
     },
     mounted() {
       // now you can use someMethod with args in your component 
       this.someMethod('the arg');
     },
     methods: {
     ...mapActions(['someMethod'])
     },       
}
</script>
```

the first argument of an action is the store itself, so you can access the state from there. same as the dispatch and commit functions.

**NOTE** that an action can **only** recieve one paramether (payload) so if you need to send more, you will have to wrap all of them in an object or array

```
this.someMethod({ arg1, arg2, ...});
```

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access, it is on their docs

Comment: @Jonos is most probably right because when you look for a getter you look for cache. Otherwise the non-cached getter with arguments is the method. You arrive at the same side effect.

Answer (score 1):

For those struggeling with the following vuex notation to call a getter: `$this.$store.getters['store/someMethod']`

You just need to implement your getter method as follow :

```js
new Vuex.Store({
  getters: {
    someMethod: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.things.find(thing => thing.id === id)
    }
  },
})
```

And call the `someMethod` getter by adding the `id` parameter like this :

```js
$this.$store.getters['store/someMethod'](thing.id)
```