# How to access the getter from another vuex module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Within a vuex getter I know it is possible to access the state from another vuex module like so:

```
pages: (state, getters, rootState) => {
    console.log(rootState);
}
```

How can I access a getter from another vuex module instead of the state though?

I have another vuex module called **filters** that I need to access, I have tried this:

```
rootState.filters.activeFilters
```

Where `activeFilters` is my getter but this does not work. using `rootState.filters.getters.activeFilters` also does not work.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Had to dig through the documentation but I found it:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html

(Ctrl+F search for RootGetters on that page)

My code becomes:

```
pages: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => {}
```

Beware that all rootGetters are global and you no longer use it like rootState where you would prefix the state by the module name.

You simply call a getter from another module like so:

```
rootGetters.activeFilters
```

Hopefully this will help someone out in the future who is running into this as well.

Comment: If the module of the getter you're accessing is namespaced, you'll need to use `rootGetters['moduleName/getterName']`.

Comment: @thanksd and if we want to pass argument to  'moduleName/getterName', what is the syntax then?

Comment: @JohnOveriron getters don't take in arguments, so I'm not sure what you're referring to. Your getter could return a function which takes in arguments and you could do that like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503527/vuexjs-getter-with-argument

Comment: They do. Even in the discussion You point to, there are examples with getter with argument. And in official doc: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access
And I just struggle to call them with param using rootGetters['module/getterName'] notation

Comment: @JohnOveriron the example you linked to is a getter that returns a function which itself accepts an argument (its a subtle distinction). But this does not happen out of the box; you would need to specifically implement your `rootGetters['module/getterName']` getter to return a function as in your linked example. Once you do, then you would be able to pass an argument to that returned function via `rootGetters['module/getterName'](myArg)`.

Comment: @thanksd mentioning the `()` was actually important for me to call it from an action. I just wanted the getter to be called so I had to call it this way `context.rootGetters['module/getterName']()`

Comment: If your getter is async, you can get the value the following way (Typescript): `const myData = (await context.rootGetters['module/getterName']()) as MyType`

Answer (score 39):

If you want to access global/namespaced `getter` from the module, Here is how you can,

```js
getters: {
    // `getters` is localized to this module's getters
    // you can use rootGetters via 4th argument of getters
    someGetter (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
        rootGetters.someOtherGetter //'someOtherGetter' global getter
        rootGetters['bar/someOtherGetter'] //'bar/someOtherGetter' namespaced getter
    },
    ...
},
```

Here is the way to access `actions`, Also includes usage of `action` and `mutations` for reference.

```
actions: {
      // dispatch and commit are also localized for this module
      // they will accept `root` option for the root dispatch/commit
      someAction ({ dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters }) {
      
        rootGetters.someGetter //'someGetter' global getter
        rootGetters['bar/someGetter'] //'bar/someGetter' namespaced getter

        dispatch('someOtherAction') //'someOtherAction' local action
        dispatch('someOtherAction', null, { root: true }) //'someOtherAction' namespaced action

        commit('someMutation') //'someMutation' local mutation
        commit('someMutation', null, { root: true }) //'someMutation' namespaced mutation
      },
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested (and namespaced) modules, you can do the following to access the getters of a module that is nested inside another module (e.g. in Vue.js):

```
this.$store.getters['outerModuleName/innerModuleName/nameOfTheGetter']
```