# How to check the stock for each product in the cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am storing my cart in Vuex and I am adding products to the cart with API calls. What I am trying to do is according to the stock of each product, I want to disable the API call. So in my getetrs:

```
export const checkStock = (state) => {
    let stockAvailable = true;
    state.cart.forEach(item => {
        if(item.product.attributes.stock <= item.amount){
            stockAvailable = false;
        }
    })
    return stockAvailable;
}
```

I am checking the stock and if the stock which is right.
And in Product component where I am making the API call and add the products to the cart, and I am getting the checkStock function from the getters.js file:

```
checkStockAvailability() {
            return this.$store.getters.checkStock;
        },
addToCart: function () {
            this.amount = this.itemsCount !== "" ? this.itemsCount : 1;
            if(this.variationId != null) {
                this.warningMessage = false;
                    if(this.checkStockAvailability()) {
                        cartHelper.addToCart(this.product.id, this.variationId, this.amount, (response) => {
                            this.$store.dispatch('addProductToCart', {
                                product: this.product,
                                variation: this.variationId,
                                amount: parseInt(this.amount)
                            })
                        });
                    }
            } else {
                this.warningMessage = true;
            }

        },
```

So what these 2 functions are doing exactly is: For example, I am adding Product 1 which has 5 stocks, and as soon as I add these 5, I cannot add more which is also right. But I cannot also add Product 2 which has enough stock.
So I think I need to change my checkStock function as a product but I don't know how to do it. So please have a look at my question and let me know any advice.

Comment: "But I cannot also add Product 2 which has enough stock". So, if you have 5 product A and 5 product B, then you can add 5 product A but you can't add any product B (even though you have stock for product B)? It is a bit confusing your wording

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it is

Comment: in other words: `if I have added all stock products for any product, then I can't add any other product in my cart` ?

Comment: So for example product A has 5 stock and product B has 6 stock, if I add 5-time product A, it is not possible to add Product B. For another case, if I add 3 time Product A, I can add 6 times Product B, but this time again, I cannot add anything more. So, checkStock goes false for one product and it never goes true again for other product

Comment: Does @Javier M answers your question?

Comment: @null a bit but I am looking for how to pass the arguments to getters function. Edited my question

Comment: This will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288003/4581336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understood correctly, when product A has 5 items in stock, and you buy these 5 items, product B (which as N items in stock as well), is being marked as out of stock as well.

The problem seems to be in your function `checkStock`, since you're doing a `forEach` operation, and, **as soon as you see ONE product with not enough items available, you set `stockAvailable` as false**, and return this value. Hence, this function doesn't depend on the product you're asking for but for any of them to not be sufficient for the purchase. You'll need to pass the Product name or id (whatever suits best for you).

As a reference:

```js
export const checkStock = (state, productName) => {
    let stockAvailable = true;
    state.cart.forEach(item => {
        // First, you search for your product
        if(item.product.name === productName) {
          // Then you check if there is enough stock available
          if(item.product.attributes.stock <= item.amount){
              stockAvailable = false;
          }
        }
    })
    return stockAvailable;
}
```

The final implementation will depend on the configuration of your `item` object. You might search by id instead of name. Also, you could search for this specific product in your `state` object as a dictionary instead of looping through all products.

Comment: Could you also specify how I will send the productName? Because I am getting it from the getters. Please have a look, I updated my answer

Comment: I added this: checkStockAvailability() {
            return this.$store.getters.checkStock;
        },